# Running Python script in Django from submit

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Perhaps there is a different way of going about this problem, but I am fairly new to using Django.

I have written a custom Python script and would like to run a function or .py file when a user presses a "submit" button on the webpage.

How can I get a parameter to be passed into a Python function from a submit button using Django?

Comment: You can pass it with a post request

Comment: something like <form method=POST>? If so, how do I bring the information there into that specific function. Linking it all up is troubling me

Answer (score 8):

Typically what is done is you'd have your form submit a post request. You'd then intercept the request in your urls.py, where you'd call your function.  So if your form looks like this:

```
<form action="submit" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="info"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

your urls.py would have something like this:

```
url(r'^submit', views.submit)
```

and your views.py would have the function that would get the parameters that were passed through the post:

```
def submit(request):
    info=request.POST['info']
    # do something with info
```

This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/) gives a more in depth explanation.

Comment: It gives me the following error doing this way:

*AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'submit'.*

What's the cause of that?

Note: the form is inside of a file called header.html

Comment: @tiagoperes I'd check to make sure you've defined a submit function on the view that you're using

Comment: This is how it looks: 
def submit(request):
    if request.method== 'POST':
        info=request.POST['name']
        # do something with info

Comment: just like in your answer but with name instead of info

Answer (score 5):

After googling for a couple of days, i managed to piece together some solution on this question, which i needed for my project.

SwankSwashbucklers gave the general approach and i just wanted to add to it to complete the circle. This might not be the only solution so i am just giving one working example. So.. your template should contain the following code (as above with some extras):

**your_template.html**

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block main_content %}
<form action="your_view_url" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_table }}
  // <input type="text" name="info_name" value="info_value">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p> Post Data: {{ info }} </p>
<p> Result: {{ output }} </p>
{% endblock main_content %}
```

If you defined your form in **forms.py** and/or using your models for form rendering, then examine the rendered HTML to find out what was given to the "value" attributes rendered by Django in the form. "value" is what will be submitted in your POST request.

Your defined view will display the form, and also will process it once submited, so you will have 2 sections in it with an 'if' statement.
Django uses "GET" to open views, so the initial rendering display blank form

**views.py**

```
import subprocess

def your_view_name(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    form = your_form_name() 
  else:
    if form.is_valid():
      info = request.POST['info_name']
      output = script_function(info) 
      // Here you are calling script_function, 
      // passing the POST data for 'info' to it;
      return render(request, 'your_app/your_template.html', {
        'info': info,
        'output': output,
      })
  return render(request, 'your_app/your_template.html', {
    'form': form,
  })

def script_function( post_from_form )
  print post_from_form //optional,check what the function received from the submit;
  return subprocess.check_call(['/path/to/your/script.py', post_from_form])
```

**forms.py**

```
class your_form_name(forms.Form):
  error_css_class = 'error' //custom css for form errors - ".error";
  required_css_class = 'required' //custom css for required fields - ".required";
  info_text = forms.CharField()
```

The "info_text" is what will be rendered in the template as in "input" field when you call **form = your_form_name()** . More on Django forms is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/

When you press submit, the form will submit the data back to itself, so your view will pick that its a POST and will run **is_valid** , and then the value of **output** will be the error code returned by **subprocess.check_call** . If your script run OK, the value of "output" will be "0".

This is for "Django 1.4", and "Python 2.6". Latest versions have **subprocess.check_output** which can actually return the output from the script so you can render it back on the template.

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

In django 1.11 and python 3.6, I had to use

```
return subprocess.run(['python', 'path_to_script//prog17.py', post_from_form], shell=False, timeout=1800)
```

The rest of @kossta's code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What @SwankSwashbucklers says is the way to go.

If you also want to maintain your script separate from the view, you can also use a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/) and use [`call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) to call it in the view. This way you can run the script from the command line as well with `manage.py mycommand [myargument]`.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the last part(calling the python script), @kosstas's code ran perfectly in my system.  I am sharing what I had different. I am using **Python 3.8** and **Django 3.1.** I had to use -

```
return subprocess.run(['python', 'windows_path_like_D:\\path_to_script\\prog17.py', post_from_form], shell=False, timeout=1800)
```

This code did not display the output in my system. To see the output, I had to put "**stdout=PIPE**" in place of "**timeout=1800**". That is:

```
output = run([sys.executable,'windows_path_like_D:\\path_to_script\\prog17.py', model_name], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
```

For this at the top, I had to include:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE
```

This was a great relief to me to see the output in my own eyes instantly!

Answer (score -1):

> > python manage.py <your_script_name>

Here script name is ur python file .No need to mention .py extenstion.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.